# Should not this question be closed outright for being a writing request?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10987/request-letter-to-bank-manager

This question seems to be plainly asking about how to write a particular type of letter. As per our [site's FAQ](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), this one should be off-topic as being a writing request. Also this question is not so special anyway and [one answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/10989/91) copy-pasted an answer from one of the Google links presented, as admitted by the asnwerer himself; hence it can be seen that the OP even did not Google his problem to get the solution to his simple problem. However no close vote is still posted as of now. So is the community thinking here not to close the question although in bare eyes, it looks off-topic?

Comment: **You** can vote to close.  Either enter a custom close reason (if appropriate) or leave a comment explaining your reasoning.  When it pops up in the review queue, other users can decide whether they agree or disagree.

Comment: @snailboat, Actually I know the system. I am just urging the community to take the appropriate step. That's all.

Comment: I wondered the same thing when I first ran across that question. However, at the time, there were no close votes, and no negative comments. As a moderator, I could have closed the question, but I opted to leave it open for a little while, seeing that it had some activity, but no close votes. I didn't want to jump the gun. Had you cast a close vote, I might have handled it differently.

Comment: I agree it's off-topic, but I also would have handled this the same way @J.R. did; when a question type we haven't seen much of seems blatantly off-topic to me but has acquired no close votes, down votes, or comments suggesting it might be off-topic, I'll either consult with my fellow mods or wait for the community to do something (or both). In this case we now have the three of us in agreement, so I've closed the question for now (if someone else disagrees in response to this meta post, we can reevaluate). I've noticed close votes come in more quickly when one of the custom OT reasons apply.

Comment: @WendiKidd, Actually it is the same reason, I did not cast my close vote, instead raised the meta, even there was no comment suggesting OT. Anyway, after J.R.'s comment I voted to close it.

Comment: @Mistu4u Well, you're of course welcome to vote however you want, but there's a bit of a difference between you casting a close vote and J.R. or I closing a question. Your vote is just that; a vote. 4 others must agree with you for any action to be taken. So you're making a suggestion to close the question, and asking that it be reviewed. The reason moderators hang back sometimes is because our votes are binding; it only takes 1 mod vote to close a question. So you're perfectly safe to cast a vote whenever you want; the agreement either will or won't come after :)

Comment: @WendiKidd Should I have flagged the question instead of providing an answer? I thought it likely that it was off-topic. Does answering encourage more off-topic questions?

Comment: @dcaswell, If you do not have enough rep to cast a close vote, you can definitely flag it for the mod's attention. Also answering a OT question IMO encourages their entry to the site. (_Although some sympathetic users answer these sort of questions quickly knowing they would be closed soon_)

Comment: @Mistu4u: Thanks for the advice/help. Next time I'll flag.

Comment: @Mistu4u Sorry if I was unclear.  I know you know how the site works :-)  I just thought I'd [return the favor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11378439#11378439) and encourage you to take action when you see something you think should be closed.

Comment: @snailboat, Looks like what we call in Hindi or Bengali: _You wounded me with my own arms_ :-)

Comment: @Mistu4u [*Hoist with your own petard!*](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/hoist%20by%20your%20own%20petard.html)

Comment: @snailboat, Yeah! Exactly, the same! :-)